# java maven proguard plugin obfuscator

Tags: java, spring, maven, proguard, obfuscation

I'm trying to obfuscate a Java application I'm developing, and decided to use [Proguard maven plugin](https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin) to do it.

I solve a few problems with the following proguard configuration:

```
# Don't obfuscate or remove your entry point
-keep public class com.appspot.Main {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
}

# Supress warnings from javax.servlet
-dontwarn javax.servlet.**

-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature,InnerClasses
```

Now I'm having the following error:

```
 [proguard] Note: org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver accesses a method 'resolve(java.net.URL)' dynamically
 [proguard] Note: there were 18 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
 [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
 [proguard] Note: there were 1 class casts of dynamically created class instances.
 [proguard]       You might consider explicitly keeping the mentioned classes and/or
 [proguard]       their implementations (using '-keep').
 [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclasscast)
 [proguard] Note: there were 15 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
 [proguard]       You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
 [proguard]       (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
 [proguard]       (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
 [proguard] Warning: there were 370 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
 [proguard]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
 [proguard]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
 [proguard]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
 [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedclass)
 [proguard] Warning: there were 16 unresolved references to program class members.
 [proguard]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
 [proguard]          You may need to recompile the code.
 [proguard]          (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedprogramclassmember)
 [proguard] Error: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: I thought that the warnings were pretty much self explanatory.  You need to add some missing JARs (maven dependencies?).  You need to add some more -keep and/or -keepclassmembers directives.  Solve those problems and then see if there are others.

Comment: For more details of the problems, running maven with the `-X` should give you verbose warnings.